# Displaying JsonResult inside data point ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I'm using MVC 5 with AngularJS and I'm stuck how to insert into my ChartJS Controller.

.CS Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetTodaySoFar()
    {
        TodaySoFarModel todaysofarModel = new TodaySoFarModel();

        todaysofarModel.TodaySoFar.Add(new TodaySoFarItemModel { TodaySoFarData = "[22,44,55]" });

        return Json(todaysofarModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my Controller which is getting Data.

```
    $http.get('/revenue/gettodaysofar').success(function (data) {
    //debugger;
    $scope.todaysofar = data.TodaySoFar;
    console.log($scope.todaysofar);
    $scope.loading = false;
})


$scope.revenueToday = {
    labels: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00'],
    datasets: [
      {
          label: 'My Second dataset',
          fillColor: 'rgba(35,183,229,0.2)',
          strokeColor: 'rgba(35,183,229,1)',
          pointColor: 'rgba(35,183,229,1)',
          pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
          pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(35,183,229,1)',
          data: [] //Trying to add 22,44,55 from the JsonResult 

      }
    ]
};
```

How can I insert the Json result inside data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the result in the array of data like this:

```
$scope.todaysofar = [];
$http.get('/revenue/gettodaysofar').success(function (data) {
    //debugger;
    $scope.todaysofar.push(data.TodaySoFar);
    console.log($scope.todaysofar);
    $scope.loading = false;
})

...
data: [$scope.todaysofar]
...
```

Comment: @user2894034 I've edited my answer.. could you test this example?

Comment: Data is still not plotting the 3 points. Can it be that there needs to be a conversion from string to int?

Comment: @user2894034 I'm using the angular module of chart.js http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ and it works with the example above.

Comment: If I insert values inside data instead of [$scope.todaysofar] it works fine